# Creating a master page/Layout using mvc with 2 dropdownboxes common to all pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I will like to create a masterpage/Layout and have 2 dropdown boxes on it.
3 other pages will be using the master page/Layout and this will be common to all these pages.

Q - I have to write code that will populate the dropdown boxes. Where do I write this since there is no code behind in mvc?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest starting out here: http://www.asp.net/mvc. Also I would invest in `Professional ASP.NET MVC 5` book - it's a valuable resource.

Comment: that's a good place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to

```
1) Create _Layout.chtml in your shared folder, which should exist if you create a new asp.net app
2) have the 3 pages point to the new layout file by setting "Layout" on the page or set it in _ViewStart.chtml
3) pass data to your view and master page and this can be done by referencing the @Model on your view and layout page. if anything, you can always use the generic ViewBag container.
```

Here's a sample master page

```
@model SomeClassType
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="landing-page">
<head>
    @Html.Partial("_MetaData")
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title> 
</head>
<body >  
<div>
@Model.SomeProperty
</div>
                @RenderBody()

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So where will the code fetching the data from the database live? Will it be in the Action result for  Index ?

Comment: your Controller will fetch the data from your Model and then pass it to your View. For testing, pass in some test data from your Controller's action. For ex) in your action, you can return  "return View("MyView", new string[]{"test","test2"}) and then in your view, you can set the model type using "@model string[]"

Comment: Thanks. Will do that.